# How to list academic courses and grades on a pdf form?

Tags: graduate-admissions, formatting

Many US graduate programs [require](http://www.physics.fsu.edu/Graduates/Graduate-Application-Process) a list of courses with grades when applying.

Some schools provide a pdf form to fill out like [this](http://www.physics.fsu.edu/content/download/298207/2088715/F-Dpt-P2.pdf). However, since it is a PDF, how can a student list the courses on the document? I have tried an online pdf editor but it has been ineffective. Is there any alternative?

Comment: print, write and scan? Old school, but it works...

Comment: Will they allow handwriting?

Comment: Probably a question for the university :)

Answer (score 4):

The two easiest approaches to this are:

1. Most PDF viewers have a "typewriter" tool that you can use to write on the document.  For example, the built-in Preview application on Macs has [an "add text" tool for writing on the document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201740).  It won't turn the PDF into the form, but you can just write the text where you'd write if it was a form.
2. As noted in the comments: print, write, and scan/photograph.